# How to run multiple mongod instances in windows?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run mongod instances on port 27018 and 27019, while port 27017 already running using windows command line. However,I am unable to start as it is terminating saying, already a mongod instance is running. How do i achieve running multiple instances ?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you use a programming connection or just the mongodb?

Comment: What command are you running ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You just need to create another folders
   MongoDB2
   MongoDB3
2. dbpath for the second and third instance, 
   and run it in different port(27018,27019)

> The dbPath value controls the location of the mongod instance’s data directory. Ensure that each database has a distinct and well labeled data directory.
>   Also Refer [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/#run-multiple-database-instances-on-the-same-system)

3. `mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/MongoDB2 --port 27018`

Comment: rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("SEKHAR-PC:27018")
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responde
d; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: SEKHAR-PC:27017;
the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: SEKHAR-PC:27018 failed with D
BClientBase::findN: transport error: SEKHAR-PC:27018 ns: admin.$cmd query: { rep
lSetHeartbeat: \"rs0\", pv: 1, v: 2, from: \"SEKHAR-PC:27017\", fromId: 0, check
Empty: false }",
        "code" : 74
}

Comment: I am getting the above error Vedant.. While adding members. Please help me out.

Comment: @VdeX What do you mean by another folder? You mean blank data folders or copy entire mongodb installation folders?